# Python select keyframes at the current frame

Tags: python, keyframes

I'm creating a script to automate copying keyframes of an object, I'm using

```
bpy.ops.screen.keyframe_jump(next=True)
```

to jump to next keyframe, what I need as a next step is to copy the keyframes at the current frame which I'm getting using:

```
current_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current
```

Reading the documentation, I found ways to select all keyframes:

```
bpy.ops.action.select_all()
```

Which obviously select all keyframes
QUESTION: How to select keyframes at current frame only?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the documentation:

```
bpy.ops.action.select_column(mode='KEYS')
Select all keyframes on the specified frame(s)

Parameters
mode (enum in ['KEYS', 'CFRA', 'MARKERS_COLUMN', 'MARKERS_BETWEEN'], (optional)) – Mode
```

Should select all keyframes at a specified frame.
KEYS didn't do a thing for me, CFRA at first sight looked like some kind of a foreign language, however at a second glance, looks like it stands for Current Frame, it would really be very helpful in my opinion to use a descriptive enum, such as 'CURRENT FRAME" but it is what it is.
So the answer is:
`bpy.ops.action.select_column(mode='CFRA')`
will select all keyframes at the current frame.