# Select keyframes at current frame with Python

Tags: python, scripting, keyframes

I'm starting a script to nudge the frames values of keyframes from selected objects. However, I've fallen at the first hurdle:

```
bpy.ops.action.select_column(mode="CFRA")
```

On it's own just returns the error:

RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.action.select_column.poll() failed, context is in
correct

Similarly with

```
bpy.ops.action.select_column(mode="KEYS")
```

So I'm not sure what context is wrong here. I've looked at this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258689/python-select-keyframes-at-the-current-frame/258690#258690), but it doesn't help me as it's just an explanation of the parameters without any further code or explanation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using ops functions is not a great idea. Look at my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268513/context-is-incorrect-while-using-handler/268516#268516 That are you trying to achieve in general?

Comment: if you can't avoid using ops function then take a look at my answers here on how to override context https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269806/142292 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269893/142292 then i think you need to change code to context area `get_areas('DOPESHEET_EDITOR')` and make sure the dopesheet is open.